# Are there any good projects for converting internet slang to formal English?

Tags: api, language, machine-learning, translation, artificial-intelligence

Are there any good existing projects to convert internet slang to formal English? The best I could find was slangit.com/translator, but the quality leaves much to be desired. For example, "I dunno, wbu?" gets translated to "Interception don't know, what 'bout you?".

I reckon I can improve on this, but I'd love to know if someone is already working on it.